# Remove headers from HttpResponse (only with 3G connection)

Tags: android, wifi, httpresponse, 3g

I'm implementing an application that does REST calls to a server to get a JSON response. If I do these calls connected to my home's Wi-Fi connection I get the result WITHOUT headers:

```
{"id":"ohig40o45h6c2a5d9rdhsft2v7","module_name":"Users", ...}
```

But if I do these calls using my phone's 3G connection I get the response with all the headers:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"        
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
            <title></title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <pre xml:space="preserve">
                 {"id":"ohig40o45h6c2a5d9rdhsft2v7","module_name":"Users", ...}
            </pre>
        </body>
     </html>
```

I want to get the body message (without the "pre" tags). Is there an easy way to do it? Why do I get the headers only if I use 3G connection?

Thanks.

Comment: These are not http headers, but html. The first response in just the JSON, and the second has the JSON wrapped in html. Is the web service controlled by you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's an old question, but I had the same problem and here is the solution:

Just add at the beginning of your webservice the headers to inform that the response is JSON. If you are using PHP here is the example:

```
<?
header('Content-type: application/json');

//Your webservice code here
?>
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: it is considered poor practice to use the short `<?` PHP tag. One should generally always use the long form `<?php` instead. The short form is deprecated and may thus be removed from future versions of PHP. And many current installations have it disabled already. (the reason is that XML also uses `<?` to start some documents, so there is potential ambiguity)